# TFS PBI with reliance on prior completed PBI

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Does TFS 2015 have a way to make a PBI reliant on another PBI before we can proceed?

For example if I have two features (X,Y) with a whole bunch of PBIs under them is it possible for TFS to know that feature Y can't be completed until feature X has certain PBIs completed?

This would help with the forecasting and sprint planning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the product that is going to stop you from working on Feature X.

You can create predecessor/successor links between PBIs/Features but apart from a Work Item query there isn't really a way to surface that information.

You can obviously prioritise your Features and view it a Parent/Child or Tree view so that way you can view how each Feature is progressing.  I often pull queries into Excel and use conditional formatting to highlight progress.

Unless you have multiple teams working on this, you should be completing Features in priority order as much as possible so you can concentrate on delivering value.  You could perhaps use tags to indicate the PBIs that make up the Minimal Marketable Feature or better yet, split the Feature and prioritise the MMF for Feature X over the MMF for Feature Y.

The company I work for developed their own reporting solution for forecasting potential deliverable scope and predicting project delivery dates.

Comment: I had seen the predecessor/successor links, a shame they don't have anything in built to work alongside the sprints and forecast feature.
Thanks for the input, I think I'll go down the custom query route as suggested and then priorities the sprints based on that query.

As for the priority order note, I totally agree. We are a small team and delivering the MMF is key. The scenario we came across was a dashboard that displayed data but can't be completed until our data input functions are created. The dashboard is a display of multiple features hence the reliance.
Thanks again